# Use lapply on a function that takes df and column as inputs - reorder by percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

I have an education data frame with about forty features that I want to cross tab against a single column called 'Tutor' and produce percentages. I then want the row to be ordered in descending order from the "Yes" percentage attribute for every column

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
toydat <- data.frame(ID = c(1:12), Learning_mode = rep(c("External","Internal"), times =6), 
                     Subject = rep(c("Maths","English","Chemistry", "Physics"), each = 3 ),
                      Grade = runif(12, 0,100), Tutor = rep(c("Yes","No"), times = 6))


toydat %>%
  select_if(~is.factor(.) |is.character(.)) %>%
  select (-Tutor) %>%
  imap(.f = ~janitor::tabyl(toydat, !!sym(.y), Tutor, sort = TRUE)) %>%
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(rounding = "half up", digits = 0) %>%
  adorn_ns() %>%
  adorn_title("combined")
```

I am going to eventually place this in an Rmarkdown report that will indicate how features impact participation in tutoring. The output is like this:

```
$Learning_mode
 Learning_mode/Tutor       No      Yes     Total
            External   0% (0) 100% (6) 100%  (6)
            Internal 100% (6)   0% (0) 100%  (6)
               Total  50% (6)  50% (6) 100% (12)

$Subject
 Subject/Tutor      No     Yes     Total
     Chemistry 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
       English 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)
         Maths 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
       Physics 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)
         Total 50% (6) 50% (6) 100% (12)
```

But I want it like this - descending by the "Yes" percentage column for every attribute:

```
$Learning_mode
 Learning_mode/Tutor       No      Yes     Total
            External   0% (0) 100% (6) 100%  (6)
            Internal 100% (6)   0% (0) 100%  (6)
               Total  50% (6)  50% (6) 100% (12)

$Subject
 Subject/Tutor      No     Yes     Total
     Chemistry 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
         Maths 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
       English 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)
       Physics 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)  
         Total 50% (6) 50% (6) 100% (12)
```

I tried making a function to relevel every character attribute according to percentage against Tutor and it works, but I cannot use lapply to apply it to my data frame. Function to relevel:

```
newlevels <-function(x){
  tab <- table(toydat[[x]], toydat$Tutor)
  tab <-as.data.frame(prop.table(tab, 1))
  tab <-as.data.frame(tab)
  tab <- tab %>% filter(Var2 =="Yes")
  tab <-  tab[order(-tab$Freq),]
  ordered <- as.character(tab$Var1)
}

toydat$Subject <- factor(toydat$Subject, level = newlevels("Subject"))
```

How do I apply the newlevels function to reorder all the non numeric cols in my data frame. Currently it is not working:

```
cols <- c("Subject","Learning_mode")
toydat[cols] <-lapply(toydat[cols], function(x) {factor(x), levels = newlevels(x)})
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "toydat[cols] <-lapply(toydat[cols], function(x) {factor(x),"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to use `arrange()` within the pipe:

```
toydat %>%
  select_if(~is.factor(.) |is.character(.)) %>%
  select (-Tutor) %>%
  imap(.f = ~janitor::tabyl(toydat, !!sym(.y), Tutor, sort = TRUE)) %>%
  map(~arrange(.x, desc(Yes))) %>%
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(rounding = "half up", digits = 0) %>%
  adorn_ns() %>%
  adorn_title("combined") 

$Learning_mode
 Learning_mode/Tutor       No      Yes     Total
            External   0% (0) 100% (6) 100%  (6)
            Internal 100% (6)   0% (0) 100%  (6)
               Total  50% (6)  50% (6) 100% (12)

$Subject
 Subject/Tutor      No     Yes     Total
     Chemistry 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
         Maths 33% (1) 67% (2) 100%  (3)
       English 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)
       Physics 67% (2) 33% (1) 100%  (3)
         Total 50% (6) 50% (6) 100% (12)
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply the function over all the rows though. This is something I have to do quite regularly